# Is there a way to extract an AppBarLayout and it's CollapsingToolbar in a custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

After creating a toolbar, with an AppBarLayout and a collapsingToolbarLayout inside ; I want to extract the whole AppBarLayout in a customView in order to reuse it, and manage it by attributes. 
But when the layout is extracting in my custom view, I lost the behavior that collapse the toolbar.
I suppose it's due to the ViewGroup wrapping my custom view, that lost the behavior from the fragment.

If anyone can said me if it's possible, and put me on the right way to deal with it.

The toolbar view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_view_app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_view_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar_view_toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_view_toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

the fragment using the toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.myproject.ui.view.HomeToolBar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:title="Title Attribute"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

HomeToolBar.kt

```
class HomeToolBar(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : AppBarLayout(context, attrs) {

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.home_toolbar_view, this, true)

        //set color on collapsable toolbar
        home_toolbar_view_layout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context!!, R.color.home_color_white))
        home_toolbar_view_layout.setExpandedTitleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context!!, R.color.home_color_white))

        attrs?.let{
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(it, R.styleable.HomeToolBar, 0 , 0)
            val title = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.HomeToolBar_title)
            home_toolbar_view_toolbar.title = title
            typedArray.recycle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I suppose it's due to the ViewGroup wrapping my custom view" – If you mean `HomeToolBar` extends some regular `ViewGroup`, then yeah, that'd be a problem. Instead, extend `AppBarLayout`, and inflate the rest of the stuff – i.e., the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` – into that, using `<merge>` tags as the root in the internal layout file.

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
I had tested the merge way before asking, but the viewGroup is created by the parent I guess.
The official documentation clearly explain that broken behavior.
Waiting to find the good way to do it, I'm gonna add method in the customview to replace the attributes. when view is included, it works but no attributes possible.

Comment: What `ViewGroup` are you referring to? Please [edit] your question to provide the `HomeToolBar` class.

Comment: the view Group is created when I declare the HomeToolBar after the Coordinator Layout.
when inspecting the layout with the Layout Inspector there's a ViewGroup wrapping the AppBarLayout (all code is still above). And when replacing by an include I don't have this behavior, the AppBarLayout is the direct child of the Coordinator Layout.

Comment: "all code is still above" – Not just the layout XML. The `HomeToolBar` class. The Java code, if you're using Java, or Kotlin, or whatever.

Comment: I have added the HomeToolbar.kt in the initial post.
thanks for your time @MikeM.

Comment: Sorry, I took a couple months off shortly after my last comment here, but it looks like you might still be working on this, judging from your response below. Anyhoo, if that first layout XML is the `home_toolbar_view` layout, then you need to change the `<...AppBarLayout>` tags to `<merge>` tags. As you have it now, you're ending up with two `AppBarLayout`s, and the one created from `home_toolbar_view` is nested inside your `HomeToolBar`, which itself is an `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: @FilipBlanc did you get a chance to understand what went wrong with making AppBarLayout as a custom composite view? I'm facing the same problem right now and still didn't get it

Comment: @SlavaSotone, no sorry I have never issued this one.

Answer (score 0):

You must move CoordinatorLayout out to wrap AppBarLayout.

Comment: I'll try it in a a few weeks.